# Getting 500 server error.. My site works fine and only throws these errors occasionally. How can I better diagnose the problem?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, azure-web-app-service, netlify

My site works fine locally. It even works fine with my backend using azure web services and front end using netlify but occasionally after several api calls (I'm not overloading the server because these api calls are done one by one) I get LOTS of errors that are all the same. 500 internal server error. I look at the logs and they give me some numbers 500 1013 109 329 2144 391

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this could be

- Network issue of your server
- Server request time out

-Web app takes too long to respond for a request/response when connecting to any resource( database,different server) etc..

To resolve that , i would suggest you to to increase the idle timeout of your app.
in the app setting of your web app add SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 3600

By default, Web Apps are unloaded if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable ‘Always On’ to keep the app loaded all the time.

You may also check the [diagnostic log stream](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream) to get more details on this issue and the blog post for [Troubleshooting Azure App Service Apps Using Web Server Logs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2016/06/22/troubleshooting-azure-app-service-apps-using-web-server-logs/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added the suggested env variable to my app but I still get those errors occasionally.

Comment: I also selected Always On but my app will hang on an api call and I will get that same error. Keep in mind this only happens very seldomly. I just refresh the page and then it runs the api fine.

Comment: Another note, If I wait for about 30 seconds, it seems to work on its own again. Could this be a database timeout and then it reconnects?